# Off the shelf discriminative reranking software

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm, perceptron

Is there existing software for discriminative reranking, such as that used by the [Charniak NLP parser](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1220218), [Shen, Sarkar, and Och's parser](http://libinshen.net/Documents/naacl04.pdf) or [Shen and Joshi's techniques](http://libinshen.net/Documents/mlj05.pdf)? I'd like something that I can easily adapt for my own uses, which are similar to parse reranking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Charniak-Johnson Reranking**

The source code for the [Charniak-Johnson (CJ) reranking parser](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/ec/#software) is freely available, you can download a copy [here](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser).

The reranker is a separate code module that takes as input n-best lists of parses, so it's trivial to decouple it from the parsing front end.

**SVM-rank**

Alternatively, the package [SVM-rank](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/People/tj/svm_light/svm_rank.html), from Thorsten Joachim's lab at Cornell, is a general purpose ranker. It might be easier to go with this package, if what you want to do deviates significantly from what's being done by the Charniak-Johnson parser.